# Opening SharePoint files from Excel's recent file list always locks the file for writing

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I use SharePoint extensively, and I find the "recent files" list within the Office applications to be quite a time saver.  The problem is that I do not always wish to edit a file when I open it, but opening via the "recent files" list always locks the file for editing.  This differs from when I open the same file via the SharePoint link--in that case, the file is opened read-only, and I have to click the Edit Document button at the top to begin editing.

In an environment where I'm sharing files with multiple people, the file locking is preventing me from using the "recent files" list!  Any ideas how I could continue using the "recent files" list but have the file open initially in read only mode?

I am using SharePoint 2013 and Office 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've found, Excel 2013 will open your workbook file in edit mode by default.  This is changed in Excel 2016, for the exact reason you described (see: http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_integration__sharepoint/archive/2015/11/12/excel-2016-opens-sharepoint-workbooks-as-read-only.aspx).

But back to Excel 2013.  The only workaround I can think of at the moment is to use the special "Read-only recommended" option when saving the Excel file - with this active, users who open the file will be prompted to open in read-only mode, or give them the opportunity to edit.

For the document you wish to set Read-Only as default:

1. In Excel, open the relevant file and select "File" menu and then click "Save As"
2. Click "Tools", then "General Options"
3. Check the option for "Read-only recommended", then click "OK"
4. Click "Save".

The main drawback is that you'd have to do this for every Excel file you work with...